What is the meaning of the number displayed next to "related tags" on same tag?
On https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blogger/topusers it shows this:

What is the meaning of the number × 3684? It is not questions tagged, because that shows above as 2,925.
I'm just using blogger as an example, it is the same on other tags, where the "Related Tags" number is higher than the "questions tagged" number.
Also, why does the tag itself show in related tags? This answer says that it was "fixed back in 2018" but it wasn't fixed, or it regressed since.
Edit: Meaning of Related Tags number does not answer this question, because I'm specifically asking about the number of the same tag. That answer shows numbers for the combination of the target + related tag, e.g. [blogger] + [html].

It's the number of questions tagged. If you check for questions tagged with [tag:blogger] and [tag:html], the number matches. Why the number is higher for some of the tag combinations is beyond me, probably including some deleted posts (though SEDE indicates there are 6213 total posts for [tag:blogger], so ¯\(ツ)/¯).

Maybe the cache got stuck for this particular tag at some time (for other tags the questions tagged and the duplicate related tag count are approximately equal). When I went to the tag page as @vandench mentioned then first the number of 2925 was shown with a page range of 0-59 with 50 per page (which is 2950), however when I clicked on page 59 then all of a sudden the page range expanded to 0-65 and the question count was listed as 3243 (65*50 is 3250). Still not 3684 but closer.
